# “errorCode”: “PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED”

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I am getting the following error when I run the demo code for DocuSign
DocuSign.eSign.Client.ApiException: 'Error calling Login: {
  "errorCode": "PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED",
  "message": "The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. An Integrator key was not specified."
}'

The following code I am running is straight from the demo app for using the APIs

here s a snippet of the code I am running

```
static string CreateDocuSignEnvelope()
{
    string userId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserId"];
    string oauthBasePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OAuthBasePath"];
    string integratorKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IntegratorKey"];
    string privateKeyFilename = AppContext.BaseDirectory + "PrivateKey.pem";
    string host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
    string templateId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TemplateID"];
    int expiresInHours = 1;

    //string accountId = string.Empty;
    string pfName = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(privateKeyFilename);

    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(host);
    //apiClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlowByKey(integratorKey, userId, oauthBasePath, privateKeyFilename, expiresInHours);
    apiClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlowByKey(integratorKey, userId, oauthBasePath, pfName, expiresInHours);
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 1: LOGIN API        
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi(apiClient.Configuration);
    LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

    // find the default account for this user
    foreach (LoginAccount loginAcct in loginInfo.LoginAccounts)
    {
        if (loginAcct.IsDefault == "true")
        {
            accountID = loginAcct.AccountId;

            string[] separatingStrings = { "/v2" };

            // Update ApiClient with the new base url from login call
            apiClient = new ApiClient(loginAcct.BaseUrl.Split(separatingStrings, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It is failing at `LoginInformationLoginInfo = authApi.Login();`  any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The authApi.Login() method will not work properly since you're using OAuth authentication. It is only for Legacy Authentication.

You'll want to use the GetUserInfo() method to get the account information you're looking for. Here's an updated example from the [C# Client Github](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/)

```
        ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(host);
        OAuth.OAuthToken tokenInfo = apiClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlowByKey(integratorKey, userId, oauthBasePath, privateKey, expiresInHours);

        OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = apiClient.GetUserInfo(tokenInfo.access_token);

        foreach (var item in userInfo.GetAccounts())
        {
            if (item.GetIsDefault() == "true")
            {
                accountId = item.AccountId();
                apiClient = new ApiClient(item.GetBaseUri() + "/restapi");
                break;
            }
        }

        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient.Configuration);
```

Comment: I'm doing this flow successfully and it works good.  I'm caching the Access Token and only calling ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlowByKey if the initial check to GetUserInfo() fails.  I did have to manually add code to set the Authorization header if I don't call ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlowByKey .  Do you recommend this or just get a new token every time?    Just curious what the recommended best practices are so that we don't rack up a bunch of one-use tokens.